# JScrollPane Screen Tearing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add a `JScrollPane` to a `JPanel` which gets added to a `JFrame`. However, when I scroll down on the `JScrollPane`, the `JPanel`s start to tear together.

Here are screenshots of what is happening (first image is when the view is loaded, the second is what happens after I scroll). Display names and usernames blacked out to protect privacy, but you can still see what is happening by looking at the `actionButton`:

[image]
[image]

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SSCCE extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SSCCE test = new SSCCE();
  }

  private final EmptyBorder padding = new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0);

  public SSCCE() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    this.setResizable(false);

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout boxLayout2 = new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
    container.setLayout(boxLayout2);
    container.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

    this.add(container, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(build());

    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public JPanel build() {
    JPanel superPanel = new JPanel();
    superPanel.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    BoxLayout boxLayout4 = new BoxLayout(superPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    superPanel.setLayout(boxLayout4);
    superPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    superPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 750));

    JPanel listContainer = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout boxLayout1 = new BoxLayout(listContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    listContainer.setLayout(boxLayout1);
    listContainer.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

    Friend[] friendList = new Friend[] { new Friend("test1", "Test1"),
        new Friend("test2", "Test2"), new Friend("test3", "Test3"),
        new Friend("test4", "Test4"), new Friend("test5", "Test5"),
        new Friend("test6", "Test6"), new Friend("test7", "Test7"),
        new Friend("test8", "Test8"), new Friend("test9", "Test9"),
        new Friend("test10", "Test10"), new Friend("test11", "Test11"),
        new Friend("test12", "Test12"), new Friend("test13", "Test") };

    for (int i = 0; i < friendList.length; i++) {
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      JPanel renderer = new JPanel();

      final Friend f = friendList[i];

      final JTextPane username = new JTextPane();

      final JTextPane displayName = new JTextPane();
      // displayName.setHighlighter(null);
      displayName.setEditable(true);
      displayName.setText(f.getDisplayName());
      displayName.setForeground(new Color(0x000000));
      displayName.setVisible(true);
      displayName.setBorder(this.padding);

      JButton actionButton = new JButton();
      actionButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));

      username.setHighlighter(null);
      username.setEditable(false);
      username.setText(f.getUsername());
      username.setBorder(this.padding);
      username.setVisible(true);
      if (!f.getDisplayName().equals(f.getUsername()))
        username.setForeground(new Color(0x666666));
      else
        username.setForeground(new Color(0xF5F5F5));

      renderer.setBackground(new Color(0xF5F5F5));
      renderer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));

      mainPanel.add(actionButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

      BoxLayout boxLayout2 = new BoxLayout(renderer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
      renderer.setLayout(boxLayout2);
      renderer.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      renderer.add(displayName, BorderLayout.EAST);
      renderer.add(username, BorderLayout.EAST);
      mainPanel.add(renderer, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      listContainer.add(mainPanel);
    }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 750));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(listContainer);
    scrollPane
        .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);

    superPanel.add(scrollPane);

    superPanel.setVisible(true);
    return superPanel;
  }

  private static class Friend {
    private String displayName;
    private String userName;

    public Friend(String un, String dn) {
      this.displayName = dn;
      this.userName = un;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
      return this.userName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
      return this.displayName;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JComponents in local variable

Comment: could you just copy and past the code here? I am not able to download.

Comment: The SSCCE works perfectly, whatever you changed to make the SSCCE removes the bug. From [sscce.org](http://sscce.org) *Make sure the posted code, displays the problem!*

Comment: It still has the same issue for me. Is it just a rendering issue on my end, then? I'm using a 2010 MacBook Pro running OSX Mavericks and the latest Java 7 64bit installation. Just updated the question with a screenshot of what it looks like from my end.

Comment: runs fine on my 64bit Windows 7 Professional with Java 7

Comment: Ah well. Must be an issue with my computer then. Thank you for your help! What's interesting, though, is that if I write `listContainer.add(renderer)` instead of `listContainer.add(mainPanel)` there's no tearing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

You have set the background to contain a transparent color. This will cause problems with repainting.

See [Background With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and potential solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the transparency to 1.0f did not fix the issue either. I did learn quite a bit from the read, though!

Comment: @shravyanga, you use transparent backgrounds in multiple places. You need to fix the problem in all places that you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding in the line `mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(0xF5F5F5));`. Weird bug.